# Prestashop edit one column in the controller field list

Tags: php, prestashop

I developped a my own module. Module have one column, and this column is write category names.

[image]

**Name** is the category name. I need to write inside name column like this:

`Parent Name > Name`

For example: `Men > Lux Men Combine`

I have a field_list under the `__construct` function

```
 $this->fields_list = array(
       ...
        'name' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Name')
        ),
        'position' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Position'),
            'filter_key' => 'a!position',
            'position' => 'position',
            'orderby' => true,
    )
```

How can i write the category name with parent name?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use this array on your fields_list

```
'YourFieldNameHere' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Your Title'),
    'filter_key' => 'pref!YourFieldNameHere',
    'align' => 'center'
),
```

use this on your __construct

```
$this->_join .= ' LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'YourCategoryTableWhereTheNameOfCategory
```

May be you can understand what i say.